# Is there a bug in .NET ColumnMappings class?

Tags: c#

This works:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;     
using System.Data.Common;
using System.Data.OleDb;

public class MyClass
{
    public static void Main()
    {
    OleDbConnection mySqlConnection =new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\data\nwind.Mdb");

    OleDbCommand mySqlCommand = mySqlConnection.CreateCommand();
    mySqlCommand.CommandText = "SELECT EmployeeID AS MappedID, FirstName, LastName " +
      "FROM Employees AS Emp " +
      "WHERE EmployeeID = 9";
    OleDbDataAdapter mySqlDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
    mySqlDataAdapter.SelectCommand = mySqlCommand;
    DataSet myDataSet = new DataSet();
    mySqlConnection.Open();
    mySqlDataAdapter.Fill(myDataSet, "Employees");
    mySqlConnection.Close();

    DataTableMapping myDataTableMapping = mySqlDataAdapter.TableMappings.Add("Employees", "dtEmployee");

    myDataSet.Tables["Employees"].TableName = "dtEmployee";

    Console.WriteLine("myDataTableMapping.DataSetTable = " + myDataTableMapping.DataSetTable);
    Console.WriteLine("myDataTableMapping.SourceTable = " + myDataTableMapping.SourceTable);

    myDataTableMapping.ColumnMappings.Add("EmployeeID", "MappedId");

    DataTable myDataTable = myDataSet.Tables["dtEmployee"];
    foreach (DataRow myDataRow in myDataTable.Rows)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("ID = " + myDataRow["MappedId"]);
      Console.WriteLine("FirstName = " + myDataRow["FirstName"]);
      Console.WriteLine("LastName = " + myDataRow["LastName"]);
    }   
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

}
```

Just change "MappedId" to something else like "NewMappedId":

```
myDataTableMapping.ColumnMappings.Add("EmployeeID", "NewMappedId");
Console.WriteLine("ID = " + myDataRow["NewMappedId"]);
```

to something else like "NewMappedId" and the program will crash at runtime saying NewMappedId doesn't belong to table dtEmployee. Is this a bug ?!

Answer (score 2):

No bug here.

If you change the contents of a bound dataset, this error is normal since you no longer match the underlying schema you are bound to.

Comment: Hi I don't understand, why would I change the contents of a bound dataset with "NewMappedId" more than with "MappedId" ?

Comment: "MappedId" doesn't exist in the physical database as well as "NewMappedId" so I don't change anything.

Comment: OK sorry I forgot the "AS MappedID".

Comment: Then I don't understand what's the use of columnmappings
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1621100/what-is-the-use-of-columnmappings-if-im-obliged-to-use-the-same-name-as-the-phys