# What is the use of ColumnMappings if I'm obliged to use the same name as the physical column?

Tags: c#

In my last question, 
[Is there a bug in .NET ColumnMappings class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1620958/is-there-a-bug-in-net-columnmappings-class)

it seems that I cannot use a colummapping with a different name than the physical name, then what is the use of columnmappings ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DataTableMapping and DataColumnMapping's define the mapping that the framework uses when filling your dataset with data from the data source. They are meant to be be set *before* you fill your dataset, and therefore your code in the previous question does not work.

Have a look at this [DataTableMapping example on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ks92fwwh.aspx)